# WebStorm debugger not importing multiple values (ES2015)

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, ide

In my project I have a config.js file like this

```
 export const SETTING_A = 1;
 export const SETTING_B = 2;
```

Somewhere in my code I have

```
 import {SETTING_A, SETTING_B} from './config';
```

When I run my code from the commandline (or hit play button in WebStrom) it work perfect

```
$> ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node ./index.js
```

However, when I start the debugger within WebStorm the values imported are `undefined`.

Here is my WebStorm setup:

```
Node Interpreter: ~/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/.bin/babel_node
Working directory: /Users/me/WebstormProjects/test
Javascript file: ./index.js
```

When I run it in debug mode, in the console I see the following command

```
$> /Users/me/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/.bin/babel-node --debug-brk=51396 ./index.js
```

Any suggestions why the debugger cannot import ?